# Ruby Rails delete confirmation not popping up before destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, confirmation

I am trying to delete a record from my database using Rails destroy action and button_to, however, the confirmation does not pop up and the app simply deletes the record without confirmation. I've tried multiple approaches:

`<%= button_to 'Delete', post_path, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?' %>`

`<%= button_to 'Delete', post_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>`

`<%= button_to 'Delete',post_path, :method => :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'}`

`<%= button_to 'Delete', post_path, {method: :delete},  {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>`

Neither shows a confirmation module.

Comment: Please check if `prototype.js` is loaded correctly, which force confirmation dialogs for various actions.

Comment: @Salil `prototype.js` has not been used in Rails since the dinosaurs roamed the earth (pre Rails 3). It switched to `jquery-rails` and later `rails_ujs` which removed the jQuery dependency.

Comment: Depending on your version of rails you need to check if you have the `jquery_rails` gem or have rails_ujs included in your sprockets manifest (`app/assets/javascripts/application.js`) or your packs in Rails 6 `app/packs/javascripts/application.js`. You also need to check the browser console to ensure that you don't have any script errors that are preventing the unobtrusive javascript driver from doing its job. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by following this here.

https://dev.to/software_writer/how-to-show-a-delete-confirmation-dialog-in-rails-using-stimulus-17i

Basically what you want to do is create a Stimulus js file in your app/javascript/controllers. In your case it would be posts_controller.js. Then put the following code in posts_controller.js.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  // method for alerting before deleting posts
  delete(event) {
    let confirmed = confirm("Are you sure?");

    if(!confirmed) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

When you create the button to delete your post, have the parent div container have the data-controller="posts" attribute. Then set the action for the button_to to your method in your posts_controller.js. It should look something like this.

```
<div id="postDeleteLink" data-controller="posts">
      <%= button_to "Delete this post", @post, method: :delete, data: { action: "click->posts#delete" } %>
</div>
```